# Got an error message with MySQL Database

Tags: mysql

I have got a error message with my MySQL server. Linux with 8 GB memory.

```
/usr/sbin/mysqld: Sort aborted
/usr/sbin/mysqld: Sort aborted
/usr/sbin/mysqld: Sort aborted
```

I have InnoDB database and here is my my.cnf configuration.

```
[mysqld]
#basedir         = /var/lib
datadir         = /CMS/database/editorial/primary
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
skip-locking
skip-name-resolve
key_buffer = 512M
max_allowed_packet = 8M
table_cache = 256
sort_buffer_size = 256M
read_buffer_size = 256M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 256M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 256M
thread_cache_size =16
query_cache_size= 512M
max_connections=1000
join_buffer_size=256M
lower_case_table_names = 1
[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid


innodb_data_home_dir = /CMS/database/editorial/primary/
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_log_group_home_dir = /CMS/database/editorial/logs/
innodb_log_arch_dir = /CMS/database/editorial/log-archive/
# You can set .._buffer_pool_size up to 50 - 80 %
# of RAM but beware of setting memory usage too high
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2048M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 256M
# Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
innodb_log_file_size = 64M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
#innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
#innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50
#lower_case_table_names = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually see `Sort aborted` messages when mysqld crashes. If mysqld is still running, it was probably restarted by mysqld_safe. It could also comes about witha manual restart of mysql.

You should look below those lines to see if MySQL was restarted with the phrase 'ready for connections'

The `Sort aborted` messages could also have come about from a mass killing of DB Connections that were busy executing SQL queries.